# Class with an object of type unknown at the compilation time

Tags: c++, auto

i am sure this problem was touched here many times but i really can't find an answer to the type of problem i have. I have a class that needs to hold an array inside. But the type of that array is dependable (to be exact, it depends on what is the bit rate of the opened wave file, for example 8 bit - char, 16 bit - short etc.). I need it to be defined in one of the class method.

My idea was to use the `auto` keyword to declare the pointer:

```
class WaveReader {

//

auto *data;

};
```

and then, inside the method:

```
void some_func(int datasize)
{
    //
    case 8:
      data = new char[datasize];
      break;
    case 16:
      data = new short[datasize];
      break;
    //
    etc.
}
```

but that was a stupid idea. I know the easiest way would be to declare arrays for each type but i would like to know if there's a smart way, maybe with some template use?
Thanks a lot for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `auto` keyword is not designed for this, declare data as:

```
void* data;
```

Then, you can just use an int or enum to keep track of the type of data. Such as,

```
typedef enum 
{
    CHAR,
    SHORT
} DataTypeEnum;
...
DataTypeEnum dataType;
...
```

and modify your code as follows:

```
void some_func(int datasize)
{
    //
    case 8:
      data = static_cast<void*>(new char[datasize]);
      dataType = CHAR;
      break;
    case 16:
      data = static_cast<void*>(new short[datasize]);
      dataType = SHORT;
      break;
    //
    etc.
}
...
if( dataType == CHAR )
{
    ...
}
else if ( dataType == SHORT )
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you, i was just about to ask about casting. That solves the problem.

Comment: Something like this: `delete[] static_cast<short*>(data)`

Comment: Actually, should just need to do: delete[] data; delete will figure out the rest.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to think about "what does this mean". Yes, there are situations when this type (solved as by jsidhu, for example) of thing is exactly what you want and need. But quite often it indicates that you are trying to do soemthing "not quite the right way".

One alternative is to use virtual functions:

```
class Base
{
   public: 
    virtual void do_stuff_with_data() = 0;
}

class CharData
{
  private:
    char * data;

  public:
    CharData(size_t size) { data = new char[size]; }

    void do_stuff_with_data() { ... }; 
};

class ShortData
{
  private:
    short* data;

  public:
    ShortData(size_t size) { data = new short[size]; }
    void do_stuff_with_data() { ... }; 
};

void some_func(int datasize)
{
    Base *pBase;
    case 8:
      pBase = new CharData(datasize);
      break;
    case 16:
      pBase = new ShortData(datasize);
      break;
    //
    etc.

    pBase->do_stuff_with_data(); 
}
```

Comment: The problem is that samples in a wave file are 8,16,24 bit etc. and when they are 8 they are unsigned, rest are signed. When i read the file i need to store the samples in an appropriate array, otherwise they won't play correctly via an audio library. Your solutions seems fine but that's 10 times more code than just declaring different type vectors. Is there no easy way out of this? Jsidhu solution seems unsafe though (i get random crashes).

Comment: So the principle in the above solution would work PERFECTLY for storing audio samples. I've implemented something very similar in Python some time back, and when I worked with Symbian's Graphics, the above type of solution was used for storing/retrieving pixels.

Comment: Obviously, you may want to use some "common" functionality in the base, and only use derived functions to for example figure out what size the data is, etc.

Comment: And I don't think random crashes is caused because jsidhu's solution is in itself bad. It's just less encapsulated than my solution, meaning that you have to write a lot of extra code every time you need to know "how big is my data now".

Comment: Sorry, crashes were cuased by error on my part. You're right, your solution makes more and more sense when i think about it. I will keep it in mind and see which will fit me best. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple datatypes. You can make separate overloaded functions with the same name. Depending on the type of data passed, it will use the right function.
The function can then call the right class from with in.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a union to to the job:

```
union {
    int8_t *i8;
    int16_t *i16;
    /* ... */
} data;

// snip

switch (bitsPerSample) {
case 8:
     dataType = CHAR;
     break;
case 16:
     dataType = SHORT;
     break;
default:
     // throw
}

data.i8 = new int8_t[datasize * bitsPerSample / CHAR_BIT];

do_8bit(data.i8);
// or
do_16bit(data.i16);

delete[] data.i8;
```

Since you only store POD, it doesn't matter, if you allocate N*2 `char`s or N `short`s, and you can use the correct pointer type without casting.

Also: Integer types from `<inttypes.h>` because there is no garantuee on the absolute sizes of "basic" integer types.